# Why do i get this compilation error in creating JComboBox object?

Tags: java, jcombobox

```
Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","password");
System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement( "select * from web");          
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();                   
ArrayList<String> v = new ArrayList<>();
while ( rs.next()) {
String s = rs.getString(1);                               
v.add(s);     
} 
bx = new JComboBox(v);
bx.setBounds(150, 20, 200, 20);
f.add(bx);
}
```

I get the following compilation error "**the constructor JComboBox(ArrayList<string>) is undefined**"

[image: the constructor jcombobox(string) is undefined]

Comment: because you are calling a constructor that does not exist. this is in no way related to your ArrayList, but to the JComboBox.

Comment: @Kim Can you please just inline images that are usable as inlined images? How is that edit now helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there!!
JCombobox takes arguments as String Array. You will have to convert it or add it manually

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","password");
System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement( "select * from web");          

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();                   
bx = new JComboBox();
while ( rs.next()) 
{
    String s = rs.getString(1);                               
    bx.addItem(s);    
} 


bx.setBounds(150, 20, 200, 20);
f.add(bx);
```

}